# PHP newspaper software

Tags: php

Does anybody know of an online PHP newspaper system? It wouldn't have to have any specific features, it just needs to function as a newspaper. I really need this, and any answers would be appreciated.

I would like to make a developers newspaper. This isn't just my own movement, by the way.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/ - Won't wordpress, a blog software, work?

Comment: Can you expand upon what you're wanting to offer? What about throwing Wordpress together with a custom theme to get what you want?

Comment: I will look into Wordpress, but I was hoping somebody would know of a system built for this already. Not that Wordpress isn't kind of a generic tool, but I want something made _specifically_ for a newspaper. If there isn't one, then Wordpress could function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openpublish is a fantastic out of the box ready to rock distribution of the Drupal CMS specifically for news media outlets..check it out:

[openpublishapp.com](http://openpublishapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What, precisely, do you need that can't be covered by a blog, or other standard Content Management System?  See [here](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/) for CMS features.